# Import SVN folder structure to Git Repo without history & users

Tags: git, svn

I am looking for an easy approach to import some inherited SVN code (which although is in SVN folder structure containing branches/tags and trunk, doesn't have any .svn folders and hence do not contain any history or SVN users etc). We just have the entire legacy SVN code with no .svn folders and with no access to the original SVN repo.

Comment: Note that the `.svn` directories would be totally worthless without the actual repository, because they only contain enough data to detect local changes. Anything else is only in the repository (but perhaps you would get to it if you knew the URL).

Comment: Thanks Jan. Is my option then that I create a local SVN repo using this existing folder structure and then try the svn-git utilities to import into Git? I am not worried about history/users etc anyway.

Comment: Subversion isn't going to help you a tiniest bit! Just import in git as if you were starting a new project. I'll write the commands in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you just have the latest version without history, the best you can do is simply import it into git as new code.

You don't know the relationships between the branches and tags, so you can either simply import each as separate root, or you can try to reconstruct the relationships from obvious properties like each release being based on the previous.

So you just create an empty git repository and then for each branch/tag you:

1. Prepare appropriate branch.

   - A fresh repository starts with branch `master`, with no parent. That's where you import `trunk`, but before that, you import any tags you know precede that.
   - You create a new branch from known base using `git checkout -b` *new-name* *base*. For example if you know some branch is based on specific release.
   - You create a new branch with no parent using `git checkout --orphan` *new-name*. For cases where you don't know what the branch was based on. See [git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).
2. Remove the previous content: `git rm -rf .`
3. Copy over content of the SVN branch/tag.
4. Add everything `git add .`
5. Commit: `git commit -m` *message*.
6. Rinse and repeat until done.

You can easily script this if you don't care about the relationships. If you want to reconstruct some history, e.g. that master succeeds release 3, which in turn succeeds release 2 and release 1, you will have to manually sequence and select the branches.

You could also simply `git init` + `git add .` + `git commit` in each directory and push each to the same central repo under appropriate name, but that won't let you reconstruct any history.

Answer (score 1):

The `.svn` directories contain the last checked out version of the files in your project. Conceptually, it's something like the content of the commit pointed to by `HEAD` on Git. Subversion uses the information to know what files were modified (and show you the differences) and to revert the files to their last updated (checked out) version.

Since you don't have access to the Subversion repository, the content of the `.svn` directories is almost useless.

Delete the `.svn` directories then, in the root directory of your project run:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "the initial import"
```

Replace the text "the initial import" with whatever commit message you want.

Read more about Git commands: https://git-scm.com/docs

Comment: Thanks @axia. Actually this is what I had done, but now my Git "master" has the tags and trunk folders (we were not provided any branch code). I wanted a way to convert the "trunk' to master and move SVN tag folder to Git tags, although I realize that without any contextual information (the tag was created from which branch?) it would probably not very useful.

Comment: Err... "trunk" and "tags" directories are present in the repository. You should not have them in the working directory. You can have them, but as far as I can remember, this is not the way they are supposed to be used. Anyway, your code should be in the "trunk" directory. Keep only the content of this directory and create your new Git repo from it.